# MVC : how to protect my API parameters in ajax call being edited

Tags: api, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I have An MVC5 Application, I use APIs, I call my APIs using AJAX, so my parameters are available to be edited from the Script Code file, now I want to protect parameters from being updated from the inspection feature in any browser,**What shall I do?**
ex:

```
 var checkupType = {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "My name",
                    "description": "My description"           
                }
 $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/CheckupTypes',
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    data: JSON.stringify(checkupType)

                })
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171813/how-can-i-prevent-requests-from-the-browser-console-while-still-using-ajax have a look at this

Comment: not just the inspection feature.... anything can do it (CURL, POSTMAN, just typing it into a browser URL bar). As I understand it, If you need to secure data being sent from an API, it needs to be secured at the back end. i.e. you need to be authenticated in some way.